# Z Index of image and separator in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell that has an image that sits partly outside the cell. See attached.

[image]

However, the separator line is covering the image. Is there a way to get rid of that separator line? The best I found is turning off all the tableviewcell separators, but I don't want to do that since it messes with the UI. I'd like to be able to adjust the UIImageView z-index or the tableviewcell separator z-index.

I tried `[self bringSubviewToFront:self.overflowImageView];` on the `UITableViewCell` but that doesn't change anything.

Even if I could change the width of the separator to 1px, I'd be okay with that, but it seems like you can't change the separators on top and or bottom of the tableview.

Anyone have ideas on how to get the image above the cell?

Comment: I've run into this problem with MBProgressHUD as well- most of the time it will show up behind the separators, even if I try to bring the HUD subview to the front. I've thus far been unable to find a solution

Comment: @Stonz2 argh, that's very annoying. So, it looks like the only way might be to create fake separators and add them to all the fields.

Comment: Possibly, but I'd still like to see a solution that uses the built-in separators, so I'm hoping someone has an answer for you. But yes, as a workaround you could use a pretty simple custom view. As a side-note, is there a specific reason that you're using a `UITableView` for that screen? It doesn't look terribly table-friendly and seems more suited to a simple scroll view

Comment: did you try to change ZPosition? [yourView.layer setZPosition:10000];

Comment: @mohacs whoa great call. that worked perfectly. Here I am talking all about the z-index in the question, and didn't even try that. If you'd write the answer below I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change `UIView` layer z-order with using `setZPosition`. It is applied to all objects inherited from `UIVIew`. May be is it a bug, `bringSubviewToFront` not working for all cases as it suppose to.

```
[yourView.layer setZPosition:10];
```

Higher the number higher priority.

Comment: thumb up simple answer!